# Office365 Sharepoint Webservices access via Java - Axis2

Tags: sharepoint, apache-axis, ntlm, claims-based-identity, office365

We are currently building a Java based server that can interact with Sharepoint 2007/2010 and the Office365 version webservices via Axis2. It seems that we can get Basic/NTLM authentication to work with the Sharepoint 2007/2010 but not with the Office365 version.

This probably is due to fact that Office365 version supports only Claims-based Authentication. Can we actually authenticate from Java? Is there open source support for Claims-based Authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to generate the cookie by 'manually' signing in. If you use Microsoft accounts, this will be the login form that looks like Live.

I'm not aware of any Java implementation for now.
You can find here an implementation in C# here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

Comment: It's been several years since this post. has any update happened? seems like the whole sharepoint online thing is kind of just a toy if you have to be on windows to act as other users on it.